# Feeding the input with Tensors instead of numpy arrays in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

If the input data is in numpy array format, then we can declare a placeholder in the graph and feed the placeholder with the numpy array data. However, if the input data is already in Tensor format (this is the case when we load jpg files using tf.image.decode_jpeg), then we can't feed a Tensor to a placeholder. In this case, should we use non trainable TF Variables as placeholders, and feed the Tensor to these Variables by tf.assign?

Comment: You can convert a tensor to a NumPy array by evaluating the tensor in a session. You can also call the tensor's eval() method, which accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: Yes I understand. But I think converting Tensor to numpy, then feed the numpy back to placeholder (which represents a Tensor) is not very efficient. I wonder if we can avoid the two conversions altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. You can simply feed batches of Tensors to the model. The model probably has a line that looks similar to `op = optimizer.minimize(loss)`. Then, each time `sess.run(op)` is called, the model will be trained on the batch provided to it. Also, each time `sess.run(op)` is called, we should have a different batch if we use `tf.train.batch` to provide the batch.